# [Proof Verification]If $u, v \in I$ satisfy $c-\delta < u \leq c \leq v < c+\delta$, then we have $f(v) -f(u) -(v-u)f'(c)| \leq \epsilon(v-u)$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f:I\to \mathbb{R} $ be differentiable at $c \in I$. Establish the Straddle Lemma: Given $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that if $u, v \in I$ satisfy $c-\delta < u \leq c \leq v < c+\delta$, then we have $$|f(v) -f(u) -(v-u)f'(c)| \leq \epsilon(v-u).$$

Proof:

Case 1: $u$ or $v$ is equal to c. If u equal to c, since f is differentiable at c = u, $\lim_{v \to u^+} \frac{f(v)-f(u)}{v-u}$ exists. By definition, for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta >0$, such that $c < v< c+\delta \implies |\frac{f(v)-f(u)}{v-u} - f'(c)| < \epsilon$. Hence, we have $|f(v) -f(u) -(v-u)f'(c)| \leq \epsilon(v-u).$ If v equal to c, then for all, $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta >0$, such that $c-\delta < u< c \implies |\frac{f(u)-f(v)}{u-v} - f'(c)| = |\frac{f(v)-f(u)}{v-u} - f'(c)| <\epsilon$. Here, we also have $|f(v) -f(u) -(v-u)f'(c)| \leq \epsilon(v-u).$

Case 2: Both $u, v \neq c$. Then, we have for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta_1 >0$, such that $c-\delta _1< u< c \implies |\frac{f(u)-f(c)}{u-c} - f'(c)|= |\frac{f(c)-f(u)}{c-u} - f'(c)|< \epsilon$. This gives us $|f(c)-f(u)-(c-u)f'(c)|<(c-u)\epsilon -(1)$. We also have for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta_2 >0$, such that $c < v< c+\delta_2 \implies |\frac{f(v)-f(c)}{v-c} - f'(c)| < \epsilon$. This gives us $|f(v)-f(c)-(v-c)f'(c)|<(v-c)\epsilon-(2)$. Taking $\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$, we have for all $\epsilon >0$, $c-\delta < u < c \leq v < c+\delta \implies |f(v)-f(c)-(v-c)f'(c)+ f(c)-f(u)-(c-u)f'(c)|\leq |f(v)-f(c)-(v-c)f'(c)| + |f(c)-f(u)-(c-u)f'(c)| < (c-u)\epsilon + (v-c)\epsilon \implies |f(v) -f(u) -(v-u)f'(c)| \leq \epsilon(v-u).$

Case 3: $u = v = c$. Then $0=|f(v) -f(u) -(v-u)f'(c)| \leq \epsilon(v-u)=0$ regardless of $\delta$.

Hence, the result.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to deal in this manner. Let us set $$E = |f(v) - f(u) - (v - u)f'(c)|$$ and then we get $$\begin{aligned}E &= |f(v) - f(u) - (v - u)f'(c)|\\
& = |\{f(v) - f(c) - (v - c)f'(c)\} - \{f(u) - f(c) - (u - c)f'(c)\}|\\
&\leq |f(v) - f(c) - (v - c)f'(c)| + |f(u) - f(c) - (u - c)f'(c)|\\
&\leq (v - c)\epsilon + (c - u)\epsilon = (v - u)\epsilon\end{aligned}$$

Hence your reasoning is correct but you just don't need to split into multiple cases.

Comment: I think you have to replace all your $f(v-c)$ and $f(u-c)$ by $f(v)$ and $f(u)$. Otherwise, it looks good.

Comment: @PhoemueX: thanks man for pointing out silly typo. it is fixed now.